# ASA firewall newbie tutorial

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa

I am new to managing routers/firewalls and now need to manage a ASA 5510 in a small enterprise. I used to just demand settings from our network provider, thus I am familiar with the basic concepts, but have no real experience in setting up a firewall.
Which books/tutorials would you recommend for me to manage the router?
Has anyone looked at [Harris Andrea](http://www.cisco-tips.com/ciscoasaebook.php)'s ebook?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't read the book myself, so I can't say one way or the other. I can however offer some advice.

A good place to start with ASA's is the [Cisco Documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/tsd_products_support_series_home.html)

Also a good way to get ramped up with the ASA is to use the ASDM, with "preview the commands before you send them to the device" enabled (tools -> preferences -> General Tab). This lets you get up and running quickly, while still being able to see the command line behind the GUI. As you get more comfortable you can transition to the command line. Which is where you want to end up.

Also one of the hardest concepts for most people to get with the ASA - myself included - is that rules are applied as the packets are INBOUND to the DEVICE. So as an example say you had 3 legs with 3 servers:

```
ouside: internet
DMZ: Web01, MTA01
inside: DB01
```

If you wanted to allow Web01 to query DB01 you would apply the ACL on the `DMZ` leg - not the `inside` leg.

They are a little overwhelming at first, but once you get to know how the device works they are great firewalls.

If you run into any issues feel free to post here and we'll help you out.